# kinesis-client-library is not reading from all the shards

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-client

I've amazon kinesis data streams with 16 shards with shardId starting from shardId-000000000012 to shardId-000000000027.

I also have kinesis client library with same region, app-name, stream-name and different worker ids.

I see only it is reading from 3 shards only. When the message is in different shards which I could see from kinesis data viewer in AWS.

I am saying this because it reads in each client application i see the logger messages getting invoked for `initialize` function of `ShardRecordProcessor` but not `processRecords`.

Any idea what could have been wrong?